# Facebook video share stopped working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our platform videos sharing stopped working after 2 years, all of a sudden. Sample: http://events.sap.com/teched/en/session/626

Open Graph Object Debugger shows perfect result. Please advice.

Comment: The share button on that video brings up the share dialog. Are you getting an error or something? Can you include some example code?

Comment: Thanks for looking. There's no error observed during share or visible on facebook wall. But facebook video "play" button is not activated. The page http://events.sap.com/teched/en/session/626 view source "OG:" meta section explains the implementation

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Originally, this only worked for whitelisted domains, then in 2011 they opened it up for all domains - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/486/

I just tested now with a few different videos and it doesn't seem to work anymore! 

Maybe they switched the whitelist back on?

Comment: Bug on Facebook for this - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598397860207749?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5295ec6649b176982419546

Comment: Yup, there's a bug. Looks like they are fixing it. Thanks for dropping by. Appreciate it!